# Using optional mongoose model property as URL param

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using the property of a model as a URL paramater like so
`'/parent/:arg1'` and the controller handles it like so

```
exports.parent = function (req, res) {
  if (typeof(User.profile.property) == undefined) {
    console.log("User does not have property");
  }
  unirest('api.example.com/endpoint/' + User.profile.property)`
```

however express returns the connect 500 typeerror page saying it cannot ready property 'Property' of undifined (which i expected) but I don't get the output from the typeOf check my end goal is to redirect to the user profile page to update the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error is telling you is that `User.profile` is undefined. The error is thrown because `User.profile.property` is attempting to access a property of `undefined`. You could update your conditional check to be something like:

```
exports.parent = function(req, res) {
  if (User.profile) {
    if (User.profile.property === undefined) {
      console.log("User.profile does not have property");
    } else {
      unirest('api.example.com/endpoint/' + User.profile.property);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("User does not have profile");
  }
}
```